# Autofac TypedParameter equivalent in NET Core DI

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, autofac

I'm migrating .NET framework projects into .NET 6. We are using Autofac for DI in .NET Framework projects and looking forward to move MS.DI. In the existing project there is a way to pass constructor params while resolving the object in run time, I m looking for a way to do the same in MS DI.

Example:

```
public interface IMemberProvider
{
    long MemberId { get; }
}

public class FixedMemberProvider : IMemberProvider
{
    public MemberProvider(long memberId)
    {
        MemberId = memberId;
    }

    public long MemberId { get; set; }
}
```

I have registered like this,

```
 builder.RegisterType<FixedMemberProvider>().As<IMemberProvider>()
     .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

In Middleware or in anyplace I resolve like this,

```
using var messageScope = _lifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message.MemberId))
    messageScope.Resolve<IMemberProvider>(
        new TypedParameter(typeof(string), message.MemberId));
```

So within the scope I can access `GetMemberId()` method. Can anyone help to get this done by Microsoft DI.

Comment: Default MS.DI does not have this advanced feature. Autofac can still be integrated directly into MS.DI through DI extensions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basic Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection does not support parameters during resolution. That container is intended to be a lowest-common-denominator conforming container that could be backed by *any* DI container, from Autofac to Simple Injector. If you want to use additional features, that's *specifically why* you can back it with a richer container. If you need Autofac features... [use Autofac](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html).

Comment: Thanks. I made some changes in Concrete and Registration.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use dependency injection in ASP.NET Core, you can read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0#overview-of-dependency-injection).

Below is a demo about Constructor Method Injection,you can refer to it.

ICounter.cs:

```
public interface ICounter
    {
        int Get();
    }
```

Counter.cs:

```
public class Counter : ICounter
    {
        private int _count;
        public int Get()
        {
            return _count++;
        }
    }
```

Add below to Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(ICounter), typeof(Counter));
```

Controller.cs:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        private ICounter _counter;
        public  HomeController(ICounter counter)
        {
            _counter = counter;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            int count = _counter.Get();
            ViewBag.Count = count;  
            return View();
        }       
    }
```

Using Scoped objects in middleware, you can inject the required objects in the InvokeAsync method.
TestCounterMiddleware.cs:

```
public class TestCounterMiddleware
    {
        private RequestDelegate _next;
        public  TestCounterMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context,ICounter counter)
        {
            int count = counter.Get();
            await _next(context);
        }
    }
```

Add below to Program.cs：

```
app.UseMiddleware<TestCounterMiddleware>();
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Did you get my question at least?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood.